# is it possible to using hasClass() with querySelectorAll()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just start learning javascript and jquery, I tried to add and remove classes with this code

```
 if ($(".head").hasClass("collapsed")) {
  $(".fas").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
  $(".fas").removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
 } else {
  $(".fas").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
  $(".fas").removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
 }
```

But the code is to add/remove classes at once to all `.head` when I click on a particular `.head` I want to add/remove the classes.

Also I tried to using querySelectorAll() on code below but appear to be an error with waring messages "jQuery.Deferred exception: x[i].hasClass is not a function TypeError: x[i].hasClass is not a function" and "Uncaught TypeError: x[i].hasClass is not a function"

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".head");

for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {

 if (x.hasClass("collapsed")) {
  $(".fas").addClass("fa-chevron-down");
  $(".fas").removeClass("fa-chevron-up");
 } else {
  $(".fas").addClass("fa-chevron-up");
  $(".fas").removeClass("fa-chevron-down");
 }
}
```

is it not possible to use `querySelectorAll()` together with `hasClass()`? 
if it's possible, how to use it or is there an alternative solution to my issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `hasClass` is a jQuery method and `document.querySelectorAll` is native to javascript, so it doesn't know the method. Use rather `var x = $(".head");`

Answer (score 2):

In your code `x` is a NodeList and it does not have `hasClass`. Also `x.hasClass` is wrong as you want to access each element of the collection`.

You can try by `$(x[i]).hasClass`

Else you can do `document.querySelectorAll(".head.collapsed")`

```js
var x = document.querySelectorAll(".head.collapsed").forEach((item) => {
  item.classList.add('customClass')

})
```

```css
.customClass {
  color: green
}
```

```html
<div class="head collapsed"> Test1</div>
<div class="head"> Test2</div>
<div class="head collapsed"> Test3</div>
<div class="head"> Test4</div>
```